# How many layers of indirection void the "disclose your affiliation if you promote your product" rule?

Tags: discussion, spam, self-promotion

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14949723/revisions) by a user has an interesting editing history.

1. He wrote a promotional answer (and 5 others)
2. Those answers were flagged as spam and they were removed.
3. He changed this particular answer to show a way to solve the problem without his product first. In the second part he promoted his product and disclosed his affiliation with it. At that time the answer was still in deleted state.
4. He changed the answer again and removed the disclosure and replaced the promotion with a video "showing the user a solution" (quoted from edit summary). This video was created and uploaded by his company.
5. His post was undeleted by a mod.

In my opinion this answer is still spam. It shouldn't really matter how many layers of youtube videos and blog posts someone adds to obfuscate the promotional intention. Even if the product is not mentioned a link can be promotional.

However, since a mod explicitly undeleted the answer I am not sure if I am correct on this one.

Comment: Did it answer the question? Is the product useful in helping with the issue? The OP should have kept the disclosure, but that doesn't automatically make an answer spammy.

Comment: Sounds like it just needs the disclosure edited back in, unless *all* of the user's posts are promoting is companies content (which appears to not be the case).

Answer (score 8):

In my opinion "promotion of a product" does not necessarily imply "spam".

As Oded asked: Did it answer the question? Was the post helpful? If so, then it's a valid answer, no matter if it promotes a product affiliated by the user or not.

That being said, I'd *certainly* want that disclaimer in the post, just to avoids it looking shady. I'm even tempted to edit in the disclaimer after the fact, if the original poster doesn't do it.

Comment: I couldn't resist and have edited it in. I left a link to this post as the edit comment.

Comment: Yup; where ever I see answers like this (useful, relevant content with a reasonable, non-disclosed, self-promotional link), I usually just add in an appropriate disclaimer, and let the poster know via a comment to do that themselves in the future.